# check for a specific delimiter per line - bash

Tags: bash, delimiter

I want to write a script in bash that handles a file with lines that has 5 columns and i expect the delimiters to be one single space (" ").
everything other than that should lead to an error, even more than 1 space.
for instance, that line is legal: `first last 1234124 complex no`

while this

```
first  last 1234124 complex no
```

or

```
first_last  1234124 complex no
```

should lead to an error.

I've tried some commands but everything i tried handled one space and more than one  - the same way.

Waiting to be shared by your knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -qP` with this regex:

```
grep -qP '^(\S+\s){4}\S+$'
```

**Testing:**

```
> s='first last 1234124 complex no'
> grep -qP '^(\S+\s){4}\S+$' <<< "$s" && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
valid

> s='first   last 1234124 complex no'
> grep -qP '^(\S+\s){4}\S+$' <<< "$s" && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
invalid
```

Comment: thanks, can u please explain what each flag and parameter does?

Comment: -q for quiet, -P for PCRE and then `^(\S+\s){4}\S+$` is regex where `\S` matches non-space and `\s` matches space

Answer (score 1):

If you use a regular expression to set the field separator in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to a single space (and nothing else), you can use the below to report problematic lines

```
awk -F'[ ]' 'NF != 5' file.txt
```